# Swift - Parse PFQueryTableViewController Error on loading the LocalDataStore

Tags: swift, parse-platform, reachability, local-datastore, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

Good day! I'm using Parse in my swift project, Now my problem is loading and saving the query or objects to the localDataStore, I tried this method

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as CustomPFTableViewCell!
        if cell == nil {
            cell = CustomPFTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }


        // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
        if let placeName = object?["placeName"] as? String {
            cell.cellName.text = placeName
        }
        if let station = object?["station"] as? String {
            cell.cellDetail.text = station
        }
        if let placeImg = object?["placeImg"] as? String {


            let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: placeImg, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
           // var decodedimage = UIImage(data: decodedData!)
            var finImage = UIImage(data: decodedData!)
            cell.cellBgImg.image = finImage



        }

        PFObject.pinAllInBackground(self.objects, block: { (succeeded, error) -> Void in

            if (error == nil) {
            }else {
                println(error!.userInfo)
            }
        })



        return cell
    }
```

now in my queryForTable method i have this

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {

        // Start the query object
        var query = PFQuery(className: "Places")

        // Add a where clause if there is a search criteria
        if searchBar.text != "" {
            query.whereKey("filterKeyword", containsString: searchBar.text.lowercaseString)
        }

        // Order the results
        query.orderByAscending("placeName")

        var cReturn = PFQuery()

        if (IJReachability.isConnectedToNetwork()) {

            cReturn = query

        } else {

            cReturn = query.fromLocalDatastore()

        }

        return cReturn
    }
```

As you can see, I'm using `Reachability` to check if the device is connected to the internet. If not, The query will return `query.fromLocalDataStore` and if the device is connected it will return the normal `query` to get the latest data.

Now, my problem is when I'm turning off the internet to test it, it gives me an error `'Method requires Pinning enabled.'` which i already did in `tableView` method

```
PFObject.pinAllInBackground(self.objects, block: { (succeeded, error) -> Void in

            if (error == nil) {
            }else {
                println(error!.userInfo)
            }
        })
```

What do you think I did wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should put the method where you pin the objects inside your `objectsDidLoad()` method and not in your `cellForRowAtindexPath()` method.

Comment: I did what you said, But I still got the same error.

Comment: @LEVISOGCPAS updated my answer, try `objectsDidLoad`

Comment: Yup, Still the same :(

Comment: When you're connected to the network, does `objectsDidLoad()` get called? Also are you sure that you did `Parse.enableLocalDataStore()` in your `AppDelegate`?

Comment: Thanks! I can't belive i missed that `Parse.enableLocalDataStore()`. lol

Comment: @LEVISOGCPAS haha it happens to the best of us! Glad I could help!